# Dynamic widths of all but one elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to code more "responsive" after reading Ethan Marcote's **[A Book Apart](http://www.abookapart.com/)**.

I have come up with a case which I'm not sure how to solve. In a `li` element, I have four different `div`s. The first one cannot change width or height (I know this isn't responsive but the image size must remain the same within it). The other three `div`s can stretch as they are just text.

Now, I know I can set the `div`s to have different percentages of their parent width, which is fine, except for the fact that div1 HAS to be a defined pixel width. This throws out the calculations for the other percentages (browser width - 77px is going to be a different number for different browser sizes), so what shall I do?

I've whipped up this to help illustrate my problem.

[image]

As I mention, I realise I can use JS to set a container div's width on document load and resize but that seems, well, not so great.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe table somethings can help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            li { display: table; clear: both; width: 100% }
            li div { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid blue; height: 1em }
            .div1 { min-width: 65px; max-width: 65px }
            .div2 { width: 60% }
            .div3 { width: 10% }
            .div4 { width: 30% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="div1"></div>
                <div class="div2"></div>
                <div class="div3"></div>
                <div class="div4"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="div1"></div>
                <div class="div2"></div>
                <div class="div3"></div>
                <div class="div4"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 This is (imo) by far the best way to go without adding table tags to your html. Beware though, IE7 and older does not support display: table; and friends

Answer (score 0):

@garthen; As i understand your question is that you want `one div` have `fixed width` & other have `dynamic widths`. I did that by change the order of the divs

CSS:

```
li {overflow:hidden}
            li div {border: 1px solid blue;}
            .div1 { width:65px;float:left; background:red;}
            .div2 {overflow:hidden; background:yellow;}
            .div3 { width: 10%; float:right; background:green;}
            .div4 { width: 30% ;float:right; background:pink;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <div class="div1">1</div>
                <div class="div4">4</div>
                <div class="div3">3</div>
                <div class="div2">2</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="div1">1</div>
                <div class="div4">4</div>
                <div class="div3">3</div>
                <div class="div2">2</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

may be that's you want & it's also work IE also. If you want to give your 3rd & 4th `div fixed width` then also works well.

Check the demo for more  http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/4RPFa/67/

Comment: In firefox the .div2 seems to be pushed down on it's own line

Comment: @xec; it's a normal process but if you want that other div increase there height of any div increase for this you can use css3 display:table; property or create a table based structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "normal process", but take a look at your jsfiddle link in firefox. there you get divs 1, 3 and 4 on one line and div 2 on the next - they do not align, tested in firefox 6 on both mac os and windows

Comment: Thanks @sandeep. I'll play around with it in firefox :)